# Archlinux how to generate italic style from regular font

Tags: arch-linux, fontconfig

From the [Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/font_configuration#Create_bold_and_italic_styles_for_incomplete_fonts) I found it possible to force generating italic style from regular font.

> But I cannot find the cache file described here

- /usr/share/fonts/fonts.cache-1

How could I configre this for latest archlinux.

Comment: This is a nomenclature nitpick, but what you'd get is a _slanted_ or _oblique_ variant. (With a "true" italics, expect to see things like f extending beneath the baseline where the upright version does not, or a not having the teakettle shape even if the upright version does.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple way to do this by using `fontforge`

> - Just open the font and apply `skew` transform to all glyphs
> - Edit font info change weight to `italic`
> - Export font